# Chrome doesn't tolerate more than one radio button or check box lists?

Tags: google-chrome, webforms, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist

I have a web form with two radio button lists. The first one works fine, the second one works fine in IE, but not in Chrome - the buttons are not clickable. As soon as I remove the first list - the second works fine.

Tried to put these lists into different tables, divs, panels, convert one or both lists into check box lists - no luck. How to fix this problem in Chrome?

Thank you.

Comment: I've found the problem. There was a Panel on the page that was overlapping with one of the lists. For IE this wasn't a problem, but for Chrome was. The control was still visible, but not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. There was a Panel on the page that was overlapping with one of the lists. For IE this wasn't a problem, but for Chrome was. The control was still visible, but not clickable.